# Reach out TO x FOR help

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between reaching out to help and reaching out for help?

> Kirk shrugged, and he knew that the look of disgust was returning to
>   his face, but he was  sick of it.  He’d tried to reach out for
>   help — and reach out to help, on some level — and got sand in his eye. 
>   Screw it.

Context: Kirk asks his teacher who is obsessed with ghosts for help, because he discovered the girl he likes is curious about them. The teacher, who knows Kirk doesn't like ghosts and doesn't like him, thinks Kirk is doing something to mock him and declines.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're *reaching out **to** help*, you're offering to ***provide*** help. If you're  *reaching out **for** help*, you are asking to ***receive*** help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reach out **for** help is to make an effort to **get** help **from** someone. Kirk tries to get help from the teacher.

To reach out **to** help is to make an effort to **give** help **to** someone. I presume this refers to Kirk's attempt to help the girl.